# iPhone, Interface Builder - wire 2 controls to the same action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

Can you wire 2 UIBarButtons (or any control really) to the same Action on a controller?

I have tried with Interface Builder, is there a way to do it?  If there is, I feel there is a trick in IB I don't know.

Right now I have been making MyAction1:, and MyAction2: and have them call the same method within the controller, which is really ugly to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most definitely can! Just have one

```
-(IBAction) MyAction:
```

and hook up (using Ctrl + Select) multiple UIButtons or UIControls to it in Interface Builder.
Next to listing of MyAction in "File's Owner" in the IB, it would be displayed as "Multiple" (and you can expand this to see the list) to indicate more than one control is connected to this action.
Have used it successfully, many times over.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple buttons use the same handler to share the same code:

```
void handler (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
       if (sender == button1)
          Console.WriteLine ("button1");
       else
          Console.WriteLine ("some other button");
    }
     
    button1.TouchDown += handler;
    button2.TouchDown += handler;
```

also if you need more information, you can visit the documentation about this on

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Events

Hope this helps =)

Alex

Comment: I want to do this from IB, not from code.  I don't want to wire events manually b/c it seems a little anti-MVC.

Comment: Ohh ok :) i feel more confortable doing this in code because i feel like i have more control on it, but doing it in IB is a nice approach too

Comment: I'm a big design pattern guy, so I'm almost never happy with += on an event in the UI (it's OK in the model though).  Apple's version of MVC is pretty crappy (IMHO) in general though.